# How to disable background scroll on pop-up?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new to the web development world and wanted to know if there is a way to disable background scrolling.

I've tried z-index for the pop-up to display above all the elements, but some background content was getting overlapped with the pop-up.

I'm not much familiar with JS but was not able to get any help.

Below please find my code

```css
body {
  height: 200vh;
}
.bg-noscroll {
  
}
.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  transition: opacity 500ms;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}
.overlay:target {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.popup {
  transform: translateY(-60px);
  margin: 70px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 30%;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
}


.popup .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  transition: all 200ms;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}
.content {
  height: 250px;
}
.popup .content {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px){
  .popup{
    width: 70%;
 }
```

```html
<body class="bg-noscroll bg-scroll"> 
<span><a class="popupBG-Disable" href="#popup">Full Recipe</a></span>
          <div id="popup" class="overlay">
    <div class="popup">
        <h3>Foxtail Millet Porridge:</h3>
        <a class="close" href="#">×</a>
        <div class="content">
            <span>Ingredients:<br>here are some things that you'd use to make this<br> isn't this amazing?<br>Yes, it is!<br>
              this is getting loooooong<br>this will take me a while!<br>oh... yes it will<br>we're getting close<br>and we should be there                <br>or not...<br>Im losing hope<br>and patience<br>with how long this is taking<br>I could really cry<br>
               but we'll get there soon<br>safe and sound<br>free as pie<br>I dont know what I meant by that<br>
               this is taking long mannnn<br>
            </span>
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What exactly shouldn't scroll?
Why `.bg-noscroll {overflow-y: hidden}` won't work here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a live [codepen](https://codepen.io/smishydev/pen/dymbXrX) with your original code so you can just copy and paste if you wish.

Using Jquery, we can enable and disable overflow using some simple code:

```
const modal = document.querySelector("#btn");
const body = document.querySelector("body");
  
const showModal = function (e) {
   modal.classList.toggle("hidden");
  
   if (!modal.classList.contains("hidden")) {
          body.style.overflow = "hidden";
          } else {
           body.style.overflow = "hidden";
          }
   }; // just reversed for re-enabling scroll, as seen in the codepen
```

Comment: Your code is Javascript; not jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you have to make use of javascript and add or remove the scrollbar-properties or css-class using a hashchange event-listener for example:

```js
window.addEventListener("hashchange", event => {
  const newHash = new URL(event.newURL).hash,
    el = document.getElementById(newHash.substr(1));
  if (el && el.classList && el.classList.contains("overlay")) {
    document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
    // or document.body.classList.add("bg-noscroll");
  } else {
    document.body.style.overflow = "";
    // or document.body.classList.remove("bg-noscroll");
  }
});
```

Starting from [chromium 101](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/b575df2582d8cbdcc3d322f19756c2a287d41bbd) the support for the `:has()`-selector has been implemented (experimental flag only) and the current chromium 105 dev channel brings the `:has()`-selector [enabled by default](https://caniuse.com/css-has).

With the `has()`-selector it will be possible using:

```css
body:has(.overlay:target) {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Keep also mind, it may take some more time for other browsers to implement the `has()`-selector. Therefor the best would be to stick with the javascript method for a while.